# how can i get active tab's index using id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i want get active tab's index for use '.tabs("option", "active", index)' method.

i used ui.newTab.index() method, but it was not working.
'selectedTab' was undefined

so i try to Using the id is trying to find index

but as a result 'selectedTab' has -1...

how can i fix it?

here is my code
(could selectedTab has string value?)

```
id2Index : function (tabsId, srcId)
{
    var index=-1;
    var i = 0, tbH = $(tabsId).find("li a");
    var lntb=tbH.length;
    if(lntb>0){
        for(i=0;i<lntb;i++){
            o=tbH[i];
            if(o.href.search(srcId)>0){
                index=i;
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
}


selectedTab = id2Index("#tabs", "#tabs-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

to find the index of the active tab you could use a construct like so :

```
var activeTabIndex= $('.ui-tabs-tab').index($('.ui-tabs-active'));
```

Comment: thank you for your comment but it is not working...still selectedTab has -1

Comment: here's a fiddle demonstrating this practice : https://jsfiddle.net/linskin/nb8vw7wa/1/

Comment: Then I must not understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide your html ?

Comment: I used js to add html dynamically,so code is complicated and not good to see..if you do not mind : https://jsfiddle.net/Hee92/x1rdmzLq/4/    this code is not working

Comment: This fiddle's isn't complete, or well formatted; the javaScript just ends half way through, so it's hard to work out what you are trying to ask us.  Can you abstract your problem to an example piece of code that focuses purely on what you are trying to do.  Keep it very simple and short and then the community will be more able to understand and be able to help you.

Comment: ok...im sorry..It will be the last question, '.ui-tabs-tab' and '.ui-tabs-active' is fixed value? or changable value?

Comment: It's changed by the jquery-UI framework.  Do note that you can actually ask for the active tab from the control by using `var active = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active" );` too.  see [link](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)